# Convert wrong data type to null with T-SQL bulk insert

Tags: wpf, vb.net, vba, t-sql, ms-access

I'm converting an Access mdb application to a WPF application that uses a local t-sql database.

In this application it imported a tab-delimited text file using DoCmd.TransferText, so I am using a t-sql bulk insert instead as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_insLoans]
@FileLocation nvarchar(500)
AS
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000) = 'BULK INSERT tblLOAN FROM ''' + @FileLocation + ''' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR =''\t'', ROWTERMINATOR =''\r'' )';
exec(@sql)
```

However for whatever reason, sometimes these files have a letter in a numeric column. The DoCmd.TransferText function appears to convert it to null/blank.

Is there a way that I can convert this letter to null for that column when I do the bulk insert?

Comment: I would recommend that you create a #Temp table, bulk insert into the #Temp table, then copy the data from the #Temp table to the tblLoan table.  During the copy process, you can do validation and convert non-numeric values to null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with G Mastros.

I would put it into a temp table and then run a replace command to remove the characters.

This will take you through removing any non numerical characters: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic470379-338-1.aspx

Cheers Will

Comment: Thank you, this is what I ended up doing. But rather than remove non-numeric characters I just used try_parse and returned null if it couldn't parse as its given numeric column